# Need help in understanding this derivation

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Can someone please explain the following deduction from an article:

$(1+\epsilon)^B = U$

$=>B = \frac{1}{\epsilon}log U$

Comment: Taking the logarithm on both sides gives :
$$  B \log(1+\varepsilon) = \log(U) $$

Comment: @jibounet is log(1+ε) = ε ?

Comment: No! But, if $\varepsilon \to 0$, then : 
$$ B = \frac{\log(U)}{\log(1+\varepsilon)} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\log(U)[1+o(1)] $$
where $o(1)$ is a quantity which goes to $0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: In other words : 

$$ B \frac{\log(U)}{\log(1+\varepsilon)} \mathop{\sim} \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\log(U). $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\varepsilon$ is small here. In that case, the author seems to be using the fact that

$$ \varepsilon \approx \log(1 + \varepsilon),$$

which holds for "small" values of $\varepsilon$. Looking at the graph of $\log(1+x)$ should make this clear.

Comment: ε varies between 0 and 1

Comment: @holysamosa As jibounet pointed out in the comments above, the equality appearing in your question doesn't hold, but the approximation error goes to 0 as $\varepsilon$ goes to 0.